# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery in angular2

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement expand/collapse functionality using bootstrap/jquery in angular2.

Tried implementing in the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zc1Xs8Eoo4KHJPtRHBuI?p=preview)

I am getting this error in the browser console

```
`"VM1238 bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"`
```

Based on the search in the internet suggestions, in the index.html i have specified the .js files in the specified order i.e. first Jquery.min.js and then followed by bootstrap.min.js.

still I am getting this above said error, can somebody help me with this issue?

I am trying to replicate the functionality from this [link](http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/simple_sidebar_menu.html#) in angular2